# Каунтер на кнопки

Tags: swift, button, counter

Я хочу сделать кнопку «snapShotButton» со счетчиком, когда я нажимаю кнопку 3 раза, я хочу сделать предупреждение, где пишут «вам нужно платить за использование этого приложения». И когда я нажимаю «хорошо», он будет платить с MKStoreKit ...
У меня есть MKStoreKit, а мое приложение - Video Editor ...

```
func addButtons() {

let snapShotButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        snapShotButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "snapShot").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        snapShotButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bottomTabBar.addSubview(snapShotButton)
        snapShotButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomTabBar.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        snapShotButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomTabBar.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        snapShotButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        snapShotButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        snapShotButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(snapShotButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        snapShotButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(counterAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

func counterAction(sender:UIButton){

        counter -= 1
        print(counter)

        if counter == 0 {
        MKStoreKit.shared().initiatePaymentRequestForProduct(withIdentifier: "com.steinlogic.iapdemo.quarterly")
        }
    }


    func snapShotButtonTapped() {
        pauseVideo()
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: self.videoURL)
        }) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { _ in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            else {
                self.alertErrors()
            }
        }
        //alertNotAvailable()
    }
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте  UIAlertController, добавьте в вью контроллер метод

```
func allertMessage(message: String,
                   handler:((_ succes:Bool) -> Swift.Void)? = nil){
    let allertController = UIAlertController(title: "",
                                             message: message,
                                             preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Pay",
                                     style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel)
    { (action) in
        if (handler != nil){
            handler!(true)
        }
        allertController.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

    let actionOk = UIAlertAction(title: "No",
                                     style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel)
    { (action) in
        if (handler != nil){
            handler!(false)
        }
        allertController.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

    allertController.addAction(actionCancel)
    allertController.addAction(actionOk)
    self.present(allertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

и в методе каунтера вызывайте

```
 func counterAction(sender:UIButton){

    counter -= 1
    print(counter)

    if counter == 0 {
        self.allertMessage(message: "Вам нужно платить за использование этого приложения") 
        { (result) in 
            if result {
                MKStoreKit.shared().initiatePaymentRequestForProduct(withIdentifier: "com.steinlogic.iapdemo.quarterly")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Будет две кнопки и сообщение, если нажмет "нет" то в result придет false и окно пропадет, если нажмет "да" то перебросите на оплату.